# ASP.NET SHOW EMPTY GRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to show a grid view with headers only in ASP.net.?. I need to add some rows after loading the grid. I am using  framework 3.5. I need Something like `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` like in ASP.NET 4.0 but I am not using 4.0. How to achieve this.?, `ShowHeader` property is also not working.

Comment: You can Bind the Grid with Empty Result set which have only schema.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at the GridView's `EmptyDataTemplate`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx

You should be able to use that to add some markup to simulate your header columns